# GPflow change point kernel issue with multiple dimensions

Tags: gpflow

I'm following the tutorial [here](https://gpflow.readthedocs.io/en/develop/notebooks/advanced/changepoints.html) for implementing a change point kernel in gpflow.
However, I have 3 inputs and 1 output and I would like the changepoint kernel to be on the first input dimension only and other standard kernels to be on the other two input dimensions. I'm getting the following error :

*InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [2000,3,1] vs. [3,2000,1] [Op:Mul] name: mul/*

Below is a minimum working example. Could anyone please let me know where I'm going wrong?

gpflow version 2.0.0.rc1

```py
import pandas as pd
import gpflow
from gpflow.utilities import print_summary


df_all = pd.read_csv(
    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ipan11/gp/master/dataset.csv')

# Training dataset in numpy format
X = df_all[['X1', 'X2', 'X3']].to_numpy()
Y1 = df_all['Y'].to_numpy().reshape(-1, 1)


# Changepoint kernel only on first dimension and standard kernels for the other two dimensions
base_k1 = gpflow.kernels.Matern32(lengthscale=0.2, active_dims=[0])
base_k2 = gpflow.kernels.Matern32(lengthscale=2., active_dims=[0])
k1 = gpflow.kernels.ChangePoints(
    [base_k1, base_k2], [.4], steepness=5)

k2 = gpflow.kernels.Matern52(lengthscale=[1., 1.], active_dims=[1, 2])
k_all = k1+k2
print_summary(k_all)

m1 = gpflow.models.GPR(data=(X, Y1), kernel=k_all, mean_function=None)
print_summary(m1)
opt = gpflow.optimizers.Scipy()


def objective_closure():
    return -m1.log_marginal_likelihood()


opt_logs = opt.minimize(objective_closure, m1.trainable_variables,
                        options=dict(maxiter=100))
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer would be to move the `active_dims=[0]` from the base_k* kernels to the ChangePoints() kernel,

```py
k1 = gpflow.kernels.ChangePoints([base_k1, base_k2], [0.4], steepness=5, active_dims=[0])
```

but this is currently not supported in GPflow 2, which is a bug. I've opened an [issue on github](https://github.com/GPflow/GPflow/issues/1195), and will update this answer once it's fixed (if you feel up to having a go at fixing this bug, feel free to open a pull request, help always welcome!).

Comment: @ STJ thanks for the quick reply. I will see if I can get a temporary work around for now and post here/open PR if it all works out.

Comment: @IP11 have you found a work around for this?

Comment: @jajamaharaja there is a not-quite-yet-merged fix in https://github.com/GPflow/GPflow/pull/1671